# In SQL can I use a CASE WHEN statement to set the default of one column if one or more other columns meet a certain condition?

Tags: sql, database-table, case-when

For example, if I want this table to automatically recognise that people that own both cats and dogs are cool. Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE my_new_table ( name            VARCHAR(13),<p>
                DateOBirth  DATE        NOT NULL,<p>
                has_a_dog   BOOLEAN,<p>
                has_a_cat   BOOLEAN,<p>
                is_really_cool  BOOLEAN,<p>
                CHECK (CASE WHEN    has_a_dog = TRUE<p>
                            AND has_a_cat = TRUE <p>
                            THEN is_really_cool = TRUE));<p>
```

Comment: This isn't a  valid syntax, look for conditional constraints and you will find many posts on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a computed column if you wanted to. For example:

`ALTER TABLE my_new_table
ADD is_really_cool AS CASE WHEN has_a_dog = 1 AND has_a_cat = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`

This would show as a new column called `is_really_cool` and it would evaluate the fields `has_a_dog` and `has_a_cat` in the row to determine what it should show.

I've assumed your using MSSQL server

Comment: ... Which is unlikely, because SQL Server doesn't have a `BOOLEAN` type as standard (use of bit type notwithstanding).  That said, I like this idea a lot anyways

Comment: Having been on stack overflow for a while. There's been many times where people have entered the wrong information in there questions. Hence my caveat, it was worth the post just in case :)

Comment: Hate to say it, but this answer is cleaner than mine. Voting up.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite, but you could create the table, then make a view over the table which does have that ability and use the view in your applications.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make value of `is_Really_cool` dependent on other columns in a table during dml, but you can restrict certain combinations. For example (pseudocode):

```
check (
(has_a_dog = true and has_a_cat = true and is_really_cool = true) or 
(false in (has_a_dog, has_a_cat)
)
```

Which means you cannot have rows with `is_really_cool = true` AND not having a dog and a cat.